# Django: ImportError, No module named urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following `urls.py` file in my project directory:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('wb.views',
    url(r'^areas/$', 'arealist'),
    url(r'^areas/(?P<area_id>\d+)/$', 'area_roomlist'),
    url(r'^areas/(?P<area_id>\d+)/rooms/(?P<room_id>\d+)/$', 'area_roomdetail'),
    url(r'^areas/add_area/$','add_area'),
    url(r'^areas/area_added/$', 'area_added'),
    url(r'^rooms/$', 'roomlist'),
    url(r'^rooms/(?P<room_id>\d+)/$', 'roomdetail'),
    url(r'^rooms/add_room/$', 'add_room'),
    url(r'^rooms/room_added/$', 'room_added'),
    url(r'^room_exits/$', 'room_exit_list'),
    url(r'^room_exits/add_room_exit/$', 'add_room_exit'),
    url(r'^room_exits/room_exit_added/$', 'room_exit_added'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Whenever I try and load a page, I get following error:

```
ImportError at /page/, No module named urls
```

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do **any** pages load? What is `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py?

Comment: Welp, I'm an idiot. ROOT_URLCONF was set to the wrong thing. Sorry!

Comment: No worries. That's what SO is for, right?

Answer (score 7):

ROOT_URLCONF was set to the wrong urls.py path in settings.py. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Django's error message is next to useless in telling you *where* it's trying to import urls.py...

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer - what was wrong, and what fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `urls.py` in the app is spelt with the 's'.